# computer play -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([Object-Oriented Design in Java by Bill Mccarty and Stephen Gilbert (1998)](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Object_oriented_Design_in_Java.html?id=azTjWLVC46gC&redir_esc=y)):

> Stephen Gilbert teaches computer science at Orange Coast College in Costa
>   Mesa, CA. Steve saw his first **computer play** tic-tac-toe in the summer of 1960 and wanted one of his own ever since. When he purchased his first machine,
>   a VIC-20 (which he subsequently trained to play an unbeatable game), his life
>   took a sudden turn after years spent as a carpenter, chicken picker, and offset
>   press operator.

What does *computer play* mean exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not (computer play) but (...computer) (play...) . "Play" here is a verb, not a noun.

You connected the words wrong:

> Steve saw (his first computer) (play tic-tac-toe) (in the summer of 1960) (and wanted....).

The computer could have played Pong, Tetris or something else, too.